# Junit 4 launching new activity freezes test

Tags: java, android, junit4, android-testing, android-espresso

I want to test that my LoginActivity launches MainActivity using Junit4 and Espresso, but when perform a login click to launch MainActivity, it freezes and no code is executed after the click (on the emulator it opens the MainActivity)
Here's the code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@LargeTest
public class LoginActivityTest {

private static String TAG = "LoginActivityTest";
private static String phoneNumber = "xxxxxxxxx";
private static String password = "yyyyyy";
LoginActivity activity;

@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class);

@Before
public void getActivity() {
    activity = mActivityRule.getActivity();
}

@Test
public void checkIfLoginIsWorking() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Checking if login is working properly");
    Instrumentation.ActivityMonitor activityMonitor = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().addMonitor(MainActivity.class.getName(), null, false);
    Assert.assertNotNull("Monitor null", activityMonitor);
    onView(withId(R.id.zone_button_continue)).perform(ViewActions.click());
    onView(withId(R.id.loginButton)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()));
    onView(withId(R.id.number)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()));
    onView(withId(R.id.password)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()));
    onView(withId(R.id.number)).perform(ViewActions.typeText(phoneNumber));
    onView(withId(R.id.password)).perform(ViewActions.typeText(password));
    Log.i(TAG, "0");
    onView(withId(R.id.loginButton)).perform(ViewActions.click());
    Log.i(TAG, "1");
    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) activityMonitor.waitForActivity();
    //MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().waitForMonitor(activityMonitor); //Also tried. no luck
    //MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().waitForMonitorWithTimeout(activityMonitor, 5); //Also tried, no luck
    Assert.assertNotNull(mainActivity);
    mainActivity.finish();

}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

The console prints out "Checking if login is working properly" , "0" and nothing else after the click and the test keeps going for a while with spinning "in progress wheel" in Android Monitor next to the test.  Any help with this would be appreciated!

I replaced:

```
onView(withId(R.id.loginButton)).perform(ViewActions.click());
```

with:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            activity.findViewById(R.id.loginButton).performClick();
            Log.i(TAG, "1");
        }
    });
```

and it solves the problem, but I am not quite satisfied with that, because I thought that Espresso handles all the thread stuff and would make my life easier, because if I want to perform some click or input action on the newly opened activity I have to call the *runOnUiThread* again and do my clicks/inputs/etc there. Perhaps I have misunderstood the concept or I am simply doing something wrong. Any input would be highly appreciated.

Comment: anyone? any ideas? :)